# WIX Upgrade msi installer from setup exe bundle without adding a new entry into Control Panel

Tags: c#, installation, wix, windows-installer

We're shipping our VSTO add-in with a Setup.exe file (WIX Bootstrapped) so it can have the necessary pre-requisites inside.

After the users install it via the setup.exe they have 1 entry in the Add/Remove Programs window, which is totally fine.

When we change something to the add-in, we ship our updates by using an MSI file (since the System.Deployment.Installer class can only handle MSI and not bootstrapped setup executables) and handle these updates when the application starts up.

Now this MSI update will add another entry in the Add/Remove programs, with the same name.

I gave the same UpgradeCode to the bundle, thinking that it would pretty much override the entry in Control Panel, but I was wrong...

So what can happen:

- user installs product via the setup.exe
- user downloads an MSI update with a raised version number
- user will have 2 entries in Control Panel.

Any chance this can be fixed, without explicitly trying to uninstall the setup.exe in the start of the MSI install?

PS: Bundle name is the same as product name, version of bundle is the same as version of MSI, manufacturer is the same and as I said before, UpgradeCode is the same between the MSI and the EXE.

Comment: You should not share the same upgradecode between the bootstrapper and msi. If you don't explicitly mark your MSIPackage as `Visible="yes"` it shouldn't show up in the add/remove programs and only the bootstrapper's entry should be there. Sometimes on upgrades/uninstall you can get 'phantom' entries remaining behind so make sure you hit F5 or reopen the add/remove programs window after the upgrade to make sure there are actually 2 entries still there.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the reply. I am not saying that the MSI is popping up in add/remove programs when I install the boostrapper bundle. The use case here is the following: users install our application with the bootstrapper exe bundle (because it can have the prerequisites), and updates are shipped by our very own auto-updater, that installs programmatically an MSI. When an update happens, the MSI adds another entry to the add/remove programs, even tho it shouldn't.

Comment: Are you intending the new MSI to be a major upgrade? It seems that this would solve the problem.